# Mirroring my actions on multiple computers (for multiboxing games)

Tags: windows

I'm looking for software that will mirror everything I do on my desktop to my laptop. So if I open Chrome on my desktop and go to Facebook, it will do that on my laptop too.

The reason I need such a software is so I can [multibox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-boxing) on [*GTA V*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V).

Both the desktop and laptop are running Windows 8.1 and this software may be commercial but under around $ 100.

Edit: I'll try to ask in another way. I need a program that will copy what I'm doing on my desktop and do the same the same thing on my laptop. Not like TeamViewer. I'm not looking for a remote control program.

Comment: Would it work to use the same mouse/keyboard for both computers (e.g., you move the mouse cursor on both computers at the same time)? Or are the interfaces not exactly the same?

Comment: If you know a device that can do that. Please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend Chrome Remote Desktop. I really don't think this extension for Chrome gets enough publicity, it's awesome. It allows you to easily share your screen almost anywhere chrome is installed. It's pretty simple to use to and is gratis as well.

## [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) (free)

> #### Access other computers or allow another user to access your computer securely over the Internet.
>
> Chrome Remote Desktop allows users to remotely access another computer through Chrome browser or a Chromebook.  Computers can be made available on an short-term basis for scenarios such as ad hoc remote support, or on a more long-term basis for remote access to your applications and files.  All connections are fully secured.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[Tightprojector](http://www.tightprojector.com/) may be what you are looking for:

> TightProjector is a program that broadcasts the screen of a computer to several other computers connected into a local-area network. The data is transmitted continuously, in real time.  In other words, you “project” a screen to other networked computers.

It is a paid software; you didn't mention whether you are looking for a free one or not. They have a demo option.

Comment: Ty. But it need, to mirror the things I do on my desktop to my laptop.
But that I mean, that I need to control my second GTA V account on my laptop with my desktop, while I play with my main account on the desktop.

Comment: Not sure if, in this case, "mirroring" is the word of choice. Maybe I'm not reading correctly what you are saying - would something like Teamviewer (www.teamviewer.com) for remotely controlling your system work better?

Answer (score 1):

Try the app [join.me](http://www.join.me)
It'll give you a URL which broadcasts ur screen via a desktop application which enables users to watch it screen with or without controls (keyboard/mouse access).